# Equivalent of date.utc in python

Tags: javascript, python, date

I'm using highcharts and I'm parsing a json in a Django webservice to send it to my viewer.

What I'm struggling to do is to get a `date.utc("1970,9,21")` output in python.

What's the easiest way to emulate this javascript function in python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Are you wanting a date object?

Comment: @Stevanicus I want a string similar to 1107216000000

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects the function is called timestamp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emulate [`Date.UTC()` from javascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.utc) in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

assert year > 100
utc_time = datetime(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, ms*1000)
millis = (utc_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) // timedelta(milliseconds=1)
```

The input is UTC time. Hours, minutes, seconds, ms are optional. The method returns the number of (non-leap) milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

To emulate `/ timedelta(milliseconds=1)` on Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def to_millis(utc_time, epoch=datetime(1970,1,1)):
    td = utc_time - epoch
    assert td.resolution >= timedelta(microseconds=1)
    # return td.total_seconds()*1000 analog
    return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400) * 10**6) / 10**3
```

Use `//` to get an integer instead of a floating-point number.

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> (datetime.date(1970,9,21) - datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)).days * 86400000
22723200000
```

See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment `@Stevanicus I want a string similar to 1107216000000 – azelix`
This is probably what you're looking for:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> time()
1447064407.092834
>>>
```

Or you could use `calendar.timegm()` which delivers a UTC result no matter the local time settings.

```
>>> import calendar
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 9)
>>> calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
1447027200
>>>
```

Comment: You don't need calendar for that: `>>> d.timestamp()
1447023600.0`

Comment: @MKesper correct me if I'm wrong but `timestamp()` will honor your local time setting, which will differ from *Nix and Windows?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) say: 

Note

There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive datetime instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying tzinfo=timezone.utc:

`timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()`

or by calculating the timestamp directly:

`timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)`

Comment: `timegm()` converts **UTC time** to POSIX timestamp. Do not pass it `datetime.now()` (the local time).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Fixed.